# How to cover form part of ActiveAdmin resource with RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activeadmin

I've checked my coverage file, built by simplecov and I've seen uncovered area like this:

```
   form do |f|
     inputs 'Details' do
       input :email, required: true
       input :password, input_html: { value: t('empty_string') }, required: true
       input :is_active, label: t('active')
       input :slug
       input :name
       input :logo, as: :file
     end
     actions
   end
```

How can I deal with this ?

UPDATE: The render_views can help to avoid uncovered area.

Comment: Seems like something you would do with capybara.  Visit the page, fill in the form and click submit.  verify that something happens.

Comment: I see, but I really hate UI testing, do you know any other ways ?

Comment: As the form is a UI feature I don't know how else you could test it.  I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SimpleCov to detect coverage of ActiveAdmin's form DSL, you need to create a controller test for the edit action. It would be a good idea to add coverage for the create and update actions to make sure `permitted_params` is not filtering specific attributes. I've included specs for the edit and update actions for the AdminUser model.

```
# spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
include Devise::TestHelpers

RSpec.describe Admin::AdminUsersController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  let(:admin_user) { AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password')}

  before(:each) do
    sign_in admin_user
  end

  describe 'edit' do
    it 'renders user form' do
      get :edit, id: admin_user.to_param
      expect(assigns(:admin_user)).to eq admin_user
    end
  end

  describe 'update' do
    it 'updates user' do
      patch :update, { id: admin_user.to_param, admin_user: { email: 'nimda@example.com' }}
      admin_user.reload
      expect(admin_user.email).to eq 'nimda@example.com'
    end
  end
end
```